# Why can't I update classes using a method in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use this 3 titles as tabs, changing the color of the selected one, however the state is changing correctly but the color is not changing because the classes are also not changing.[image: Tabs]

This refers to the 2nd tab, as it should:

[image: state]

However the class is not correctly updating, as you can see on the inspecting screen:

[image: Debug output]

Methods:

```
setTabClass(tab) {
    console.log(this.graphTab);
    if (tab === this.graphTab) {
        return 'currentTab';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

handleClassClick = (tab) => {
    this.setState( {graphTab: tab} );
}
```

Elements:

```
<div className='chart-area'>
    <div className='chart-area-tabs'>
        <p className={this.setTabClass('sales')} onClick={() => this.handleClassClick('sales')} >Sales (0$)</p>
        <p className={this.setTabClass('order')} onClick={() => this.handleClassClick('order')} >Order Volume (0)</p>
        <p className={this.setTabClass('ticket')}  >Ticket Size ($0.00)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the `graphTab` state wrong - it should be `this.state.graphTab` instead of `this.graphTab` in the `setTabClass` method.